# SBS 2011 What SSL certificate should I get to make connections to the server valid

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ssl, https, exchange-2010, windows-sbs

I have a SBS 2011 server that is running a Microsoft Exchange 2010. The issue I'm facing is based around self signed certificates.

The first issue is that Outlook won't work unless you install the certificate to all client desktops.
The second is that all browsers consider the domain for OWA (Outlook web access) unsafe because of the self signed certificate.

I would like to ask your opinion about getting a SSL certificate signed from a 3rd party company, for example Comodo.

Which certificate would be suited for my setup? Would it fix both internal and external issues with the certificate?

Thanks for your time

Comment: There is a lot of information about this online already. It would be difficult to tell you what is best for your scenario based on the limited amount of information you provided. Any type of 3rd party SSL certificate would work in most cases and yes it would fix your certificate issues. Please do a little research and narrow down your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Which certificate would be suited for my setup?

**The same kind** as you would use when adding HTTPS to a regular website. (For the most part it's the same HTTPS anyway – and where it isn't HTTPS, it is still the same SSL/TLS anyway.)

Therefore the same basic rules apply:

1. The name (CN/SAN) on it has to match the hostname in the URL. If your clients are connecting to "mail.example.com", then the certificate better *be* issued for "mail.example.com". It works the same way with IMAP or SMTP connections too.

   However, if your clients are connecting to a made-up domain like "mail.lan", you're not going to be able to buy a certificate for that. You should stop using made-up domains for your LAN.
2. It has to be issued by a "certificate authority" that the clients already recognize.

   It doesn't matter which one. If you are choosing between widely-trusted CAs, then whether it's from Comodo or DigiCert or Let's Encrypt or Honest Achmed's Used Cars and Certificates – doesn't make any *technical* difference.

   So you mostly choose based on which company is easiest to deal with. (Some are cheaper, some are *free*, some have better automation tools, or better tech support, or are more trustworthy, etc.)

   (It is also possible to run a private internal CA. Then your clients will only need to install *one* certificate: your CA's root cert, and you'll be able to issue any amount of "server" certificates using it.)